# vue-router: define pretty URL for filter page with pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, static, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm using NuxtJS for my static website and I want to create a shop page with filter, sort, and pagination. How can I define vue-router extend in nuxt.conf.js for this situation:

- shop page: 
  example.com/shop/
- shop page with pagination:
  example.com/shop/page/2
- shop page with filters and pagination:
  example.com/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/2
- shop page with filters, pagination and sort:
  example.com/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/2/sort/ASC

I'm currently using this block of code, but this is very simple and works just for pagination:

```js
router: {
  trailingSlash: true,
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      path: '/shop/page/:number',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create multiple routes for this to work.

If you are trying to achieve it with just one route, there are some problems with the schema.

1. `example.com/shop/` might be followed by either pagination or filter.
2. The filters may contain 1 or more items.
3. Pagination might also be followed by a sort.
4. Could a filter be followed by a sort in the absence of pagination?

So the single path that can handle all the above is something like

```js
{
  path: '/shop/filters/:filter*/page/:number?/sort/:order?',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
}
```

This does the following,

1. All parameters are optional.
2. Filters can contain 0 or more item.

But the URL might trip you off.

```markdown
# Ideal path with more than one filter, pagination, and sort
/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/2/sort/ASC

# Single filter, pagination, and sort
/shop/filters/size-big/page/2/sort/ASC

# No filters, but with pagination and sort
/shop/filters/page/2/sort/ASC

# No filter or pagination, but has sort
/shop/filters/page/sort/ASC

# No filter, pagination or sort (default page)
/shop/filters/page/sort

# No Sort
/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/2/sort

# no pagination
/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/sort/2

# no sort or pagination
/shop/filters/color-green/size-big/page/sort
```

But this is clearly not what you want. So instead, create multiple routes.

```js
[{
  path: '/shop/',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},{
  path: '/shop/filters/:filter*/page/:number/sort/:order',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},{
  path: '/shop/filters/:filter*/page/:number',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},{
  path: '/shop/filters/:filter*',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},{
  path: '/shop/page/:number/sort:order',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},{
  path: '/shop/page/:number',
  component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/shop.vue')
},]
```

I might have missed something or the order might not be accurate, but I guess you got the gist of what you need to do.

Since `vue-router` uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp), you can test it on [forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)